# How to get BGR data and data_size from cv::Mat

Tags: opencv, bgr

I can get BGR data from `Mat.data` pointer, but I don't know how to calculate the data size. Could somebody help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your matrix is continuous, I'd go with [cv::Mat::total()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#aa4d317d43fb0cba9c2503f3c61b866c8)
to get the number of elements and [cv::Mat::elemSize()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#aba7a5ef00b22b70668fba575005dfe55) to get the matrix element size in bytes:

```cpp
Mat m;
//...

uchar* data = m.data();
auto datasize = m.total() * m.elemSize();
```

An alternative could be (but I'm not so sure, so double check this) to take the difference between [cv::Mat::dataend](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#ae756e84c94cbcf4c152ed0e67edb71ca) and [cv::Mat::datastart](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#aeda6d607bfc629a95f59e7b538832172)

```cpp
auto datasize = m.dataend - m.datastart;
```

If your matrices are not continuous, I guess that you can still use the first method to obtain the size, but don't `memcpy()` that amount of bytes, because it won't be your image data.